# Is there a way to lower the resolution of a UWP InkCanvas to 28x28?

Tags: c#, uwp

In an attempt to create a neural network program to detect handwritten digits, I first need to capture the handwritten digit on an InkCanvas. The problem is that when I save the InkCanvas as a Bitmap, the resolution is much greater than 28x28. I'm favoring 28x28 because the input layer to my neural network will have 784 nodes. The size of my input layer will skyrocket if I use the full resolution of the InkCanvas.

As it stands, I draw the handwritten digits in a 28x28 canvas within MS Paint.
I then save the image as a bmp file in my programs project folder.
From there, my program sees the bmp file and processes it accordingly.
I just need help lowering the resolution of the UWP InkCanvas.
I do not simply want to edit the width and height, but the actual pixel count/zoom.

[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvcfr.png)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // sets initial window size
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(1000, 800);
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

            

            // sets supported inking device types
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;

            // sets initial ink stroke attributes
            InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
            drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
            drawingAttributes.Size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(2, 2);
            drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
            drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);

         
        }


        private async void saveInkCanvasBitmap()
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await bitmap.RenderAsync(grid);

            var pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            StorageFolder pictureFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
            var file = await pictureFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.bmp", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                     (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
                                     (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
                                     displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                                     displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                                     pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }




        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // clears the ink canvas of any pen strokes
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
        }
        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            saveInkCanvasBitmap(); // try to lower resolution of ink canvas to 28 x 28
            // other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of [BitmapEncoder.SetPixelData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.setpixeldata?view=winrt-22621#windows-graphics-imaging-bitmapencoder-setpixeldata(windows-graphics-imaging-bitmappixelformat-windows-graphics-imaging-bitmapalphamode-system-uint32-system-uint32-system-double-system-double-system-byte())), the parameter called **dpiX** and **dpiY** are the resolution values for the bitmap. Please try to change your code like

```
 encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                 BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                 (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
                                 (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
                                 28,
                                 28,
                                 pixels);
```